# How to delete multiple Items from QTreeWidget, QListWidget or QListView

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a list of `QTreeWidget` items indexes:

```
indexesToDelete=[1, 3, 5 ,7]
```

Now if I do:

```
for itemIndex in indexesToDelete:
    myTree.takeTopLevelItem(itemIndex) # deletes an item from Tree
```

the things get really nasty. With every `for itemIndex in indexesToDelete` iteration an Item deleted and Tree Item's indexes are changed even while `for` loop is still going... Needless to say that only the very first for loop iteration deletes a correct List Item. All other list items are removed improperly.

**Question**: How to delete List Items by their indexes correctly?

Comment: Go in reverse-sorted order!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to remove by item instead of constantly changing index numbers.
First build a list of items to be removed. Then iterate the items in a Tree comparing each against the ones stored in a items-to-be-removed list . Delete if True.

**QListWidget()**

```
myListWidget=QtGui.QListWidget()

for i in range(10):
    item=QtGui.QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
    myListWidget.addItem(item)

indexToRemove=[2,4,6]

itemsToRemove=[]
for index in indexToRemove:
    item=myListWidget.item(index)
    if item: itemsToRemove.append(item)

for i in range(myListWidget.count()):
    listItem = myListWidget.item(i)
    if not listItem: continue
    if not listItem in itemsToRemove: continue                  
    itemRow=myListWidget.row(listItem)
    if itemRow:
        myListWidget.takeItem(itemRow)
```

**QTreeWidget()**

```
myTreeWidget=QtGui.QTreeWidget()

for i in range(10):
    item=QtGui.QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
    myTreeWidget.addTopLevelItem(item)

indexToRemove=[2,4,6]

itemsToRemove=[]
for index in indexToRemove:
    item=myTreeWidget.topLevelItem(index)
    if item: itemsToRemove.append(item)

for i in range(myTreeWidget.topLevelItemCount()):
    listItem=myTreeWidget.topLevelItem(i)
    if not listItem: continue
    if not listItem in itemsToRemove: continue
    itemIndex=myTreeWidget.indexOfTopLevelItem(listItem)
    if not itemIndex: continue             
    myTreeWidget.takeTopLevelItem(itemIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I would like to start by pointing out that you aren't actually deleting by a `QModelIndex` but rather by an integer which you have associated to a specific item (or rows of items). If you actually had `QModelIndex`s for each item you wanted to delete, you would find that after the first deletion, all of the indexes would return `False` when you queried `index.isValid()`. This should make a lot of sense, obviously when you delete an item, all indexes become invalid (as you have found).

In short, Qt is supposed to help stop you doing exactly what you have attempted to do!

The only **reliable** solution is to delete based on a list of items. You can look up the item index from the item at each iteration of your deletion loop if you want (and delete by index), but you cannot store a list of indexes and expect deletion to work correctly.